# Reading Json String using Gson results error "not a JSON Array"

Tags: java, javascript, android, json, gson

In my project i have a complex json response. I want to read it by GSon.

```
JSON : {'FoodMenuRS':{'Results':[{'Items':{'Item':[{'@Id':'24'},{'@Id':'24'}]}}, {'Items':{'Item':{'@Id':'24'}}}]}}
```

It contains a JSONArray with first "Item" and JSONObject with second one. Hence its call results in error,

```
failed to deserialize json object {"@Id":"24"} given the type java.util.List<com.servlet.action.ItemInfo>  and  java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
```

Please help how i should handle this scenario. Thanks.

Comment: could you post some parsing code?, looks like you are trying to read jsonArray on jsonObject

Comment: Valid JSON uses `"` instead of `'`. That might not be your problem, but just in case.

Comment: `{"@Id":"24"}` is indeed not a JSon array. Dare to share some Java code here, esp. the classes you want to deserialize that to?

Answer (score 6):

The string you are showing is a `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`. So, in this case you first of all have to get the JSONObject and perform further decoding on that JSONObject.

```
JSONObject - {}

JSONArray - []
```

And indeed `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` should be encoded using `Double-quotes(")`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is valid, but not for the doble quotes (") because JSON supports simple quotes (') and no quotes in the key name. See http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Colle

However this JSON have key names that begin with @. For JSON strings this character is valid at the beginning of the name (see right column http://www.json.org/) but for Java this names are illegal (see Naming section http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). Specifically, names started with @ are annotations and you can't use annotations tags to declare variables, fields, methods, etc.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a valid JSON object. Strings in JSON are always encapsulated in double quotes (`"`). Contact the producer of that JSON and tell him to use a correct encoder.

Comment: Theorically is not a valid JSON string but Gson supports " and ' and no quotes, like many other parsers. Also Javascript supports simple quotes and no quotes :)
See http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Colle